# Como recorrer y comparar 2 arrays de objetos con otros arrays de objetos anidados

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, map, usestate

muy buenas, me encuentro estancado, necesito resolver (entender) lo siguiente. Básicamente tengo dos arreglos de objetos, cada objeto tiene un "type" que es un string y un "data" que es otro array de objetos,  la idea es que: si ambos tienen el mismo "type", iterar sobre la data y comparar si son de la misma medida, de ser así, actualizar la cantidadTotal, sino agregar el objeto completo a la data, y a su vez si no es el mismo "type" agregar todo el objeto, espero haberme explicado, logro aumentar la cantidadTotal pero no lo demás, me sobreescribe o tiene comportamientos inesperados, me estoy complicando mucho al iterar probablemente, pero no le puedo encontrar solución me ha anulado, quisiera tener otra perspectiva, desde ya mil gracias!

```
const modelos = [
{
    name: 'Doble de 100',
    id: '1',
    cantidad: 1,
    cortes: [
        {
            cantidadTotal: 1,
            type: '1x1',
            medida: 100,
            cantidad: 2,
        },
        {
            cantidadTotal: 1,
            type: '1x2',
            medida: 100,
            cantidad: 1,
        },
        {
            cantidadTotal: 1,
            type: '1x1-1/2',
            medida: 120,
            cantidad: 2,
        },
    ],
},
{
    name: 'Doble de 125',
    id: '2',
    cantidad: 1,
    cortes: [
        {
            cantidadTotal: 1,
            type: '1x1',
            medida: 125,
            cantidad: 4,
        },
        {
            cantidadTotal: 1,
            type: '1x2',
            medida: 100,
            cantidad: 1,
        },
    ],
},
{
    name: 'Tripode',
    id: '3',
    cantidad: 1,
    cortes: [
        {
            cantidadTotal: 1,
            type: '1x2',
            medida: 50,
            cantidad: 2,
        },
    ],
},
{
    name: 'Doble de mesa',
    id: '4',
    cantidad: 1,
    cortes: [
        {
            cantidadTotal: 1,
            type: '1x1-1/',
            medida: 70,
            cantidad: 2,
        },
    ],
},];

export const Carrito = () => {
const [pedido, setPedido] = useState([]);
const [materiales, setMateriales] = useState([]);
// console.log(materiales);
const handleClick = (modelo) => {
    // aumenta la cantidad y actualiza pedido
    const existe = pedido.some((art) => art.id === modelo.id);
    if (existe) {
        const nuevoPedido = pedido.map((art) => {
            if (art.id === modelo.id) {
                art.cantidad = art.cantidad + 1;
                art.cortes.forEach(
                    (corte) => (corte.cantidadTotal = art.cantidad)
                );
                return art;
            } else {
                return art;
            }
        });
        setPedido(nuevoPedido);
    } else {
        setPedido([...pedido, modelo]);
    }
    // transforma el pedido en un nuevo arreglo de objetos con solo los materiales
    const materialesNuevos = modelo.cortes.map((art) => {
        return {
            type: art.type,
            data: [
                {
                    medida: art.medida,
                    cantidad: art.cantidad,
                    cantidadTotal: art.cantidad,
                },
            ],
        };
    });

    const existeTipo = materiales.map((mat) => {
        return materialesNuevos.some((matNuevo) =>
            matNuevo ? matNuevo.type === mat.type : null
        );
    });

    // Aqui es donde intento actualizar materiales y me estoy equivocando al utilizar los metodos a la hora de comparar
    if (existeTipo.some((tipo) => tipo)) {
        const newPedidoMateriales = materiales.map((mat, i) => {
            const found = materialesNuevos.find(
                (el) => el.type === mat.type
            );
            if (found) {
                return mat.data.map((item) => {
                    const size = found.data.find(
                        (e) => e.medida === item.medida
                    );
                    const noSize = found.data.find(
                        (e) => e.medida !== item.medida
                    );
                    if (size) {
                        item.cantidadTotal = modelo.cantidad * item.cantidad;
                        return mat;
                    } else {
                        mat.data = [...mat.data, noSize];
                        return mat;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // Aqui no se exactamente
            }
            setMateriales(newPedidoMateriales);
        });
    } else {
        setMateriales([...materiales, ...materialesNuevos]);
    }
};

return (
    <div style={{ maxWidth: 1000, margin: 'auto', padding: '2rem' }}>
        <h1>Carrito</h1>
        {modelos.map((modelo) => (
            <div key={modelo.id}>
                <h3>{modelo.name}</h3>
                <button onClick={() => handleClick(modelo)}>Agregar</button>
                <hr />
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);};
```

Comment: Como veo que estas tratando de emular un carrito de compras, te dejo [este ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/contador-de-productos-en-carrito-xhro0) en CodeSandbox para que lo analices :)

Comment: Gracias Paulo, si lo mire, creo que tenemos otra idea igualmente... yo necesito que de cada "modelo" seleccionado incremente su cantidad en uno (esto lo hace) y luego mapear la propiedad "cortes" para saber que tipo de cortes y medidas ocupa el modelo seleecionado...hasta ahi todo nice...el tema es cuando comparo "materiales" con "materialesNuevos" me esta costando eso, trato de utilizar el find, el some etc...pero devuelve cualquier cosa a veces... "materiales" deberia ser una lista de "materialesNuevos": con un type y con un arreglo de objetos que es la data

Comment: yo deberia recorrer lo materiales buscando coincidencias primero en el type, que es unico y no se repite, una vez que la encuentro me meto en la data y verifico, si las medidas son iguales hago una operacion, sino agrego todo el objeto, nose si logro darme a entender [{type: '1x1', data: [{cantidad: 1 , cantidadTotal: 1, medida: 50}] }], tendria que finalizar con un arreglo de este tipo sin repetir types ( es una app de pedidos de madera, un modelo puede tener muchas maderas del mismo tipo y distinta medida, intento juntarlos en objetos para luego renderizar la lista)

Comment: Espero no haberme extendido demasiado y haberme explicado, igualemente muchas gracias por haberme contestado, saludos

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo? No olvides que si lo lograste, publicar tu respuesta para futuros problemas similares. Sino lo has resuelto, te puedo echar una mano :D